# Text format after an image in a block displayed by QTextEdit

Tags: c++, image, qt, text-formatting

In a QTextEdit object, I want to display a document made of two parts : a title and a text. The text begins with an image (an initial, placed at left), hence my code :

```
  QTextCursor cur = this->textCursor();

  // title :
  [... defining the title block format and the title's text char format ...]
  cur.insertBlock( title_blockformat, title_textcharformat );
  cur.insertText("TITLE");

  // initial + text
  // [... defining the text block format and text's text char format ...]
  cur.insertBlock( text_blockformat, text_textcharformat );
  // [...defining the image format...]
  cur.insertImage( imageformat, QTextFrameFormat::FloatLeft);
  cur.insertText("SOME TEXT");
```

I'm stuck with the following problem : the title is correctly displayed, the image too but the text is displayed with a default format, as if the line

```
  cur.insertBlock( text_blockformat, text_textcharformat );
```

was somehow forgotten because of the image. **When I remove the call to cur.insertImage() my text is correctly displayed.**

I checked cur.insertImage didn't add a new block : the image and the text belong to the same block.

Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the default mode is that when you don't reassign your own charformat, the text inserted by the cursor will adopt the charformat used by the current text fragment. In your case, it's the format of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand why the code in my question didn't work but here's a simple workaround :

Instead of :

```
cur.insertText("SOME TEXT");
```

just write :

```
cur.setCharFormat( text_textcharformat );
cur.insertText("SOME TEXT");
```

But the question remains : why do I have to add this line when the text has been inserted after an image ?